# MC cable pass-thru in PVC conduit

Tags: electrical

I will be installing a double oven that has an MC cable pigtail and needs to be direct connect. I am at the stage of drywall and cabinet install. Can I install a piece of PVC conduit behind the drywall that goes from the back of the double oven cabinet to the basement below? The goal is on the install to route the pigtail down the pvc conduit and do the direct connect in a junction box in the basement below. I think the length will be 2 - 3 feet.

Comment: That's not a MC cable pigtail, it's a special type of flexible conduit with appliance wiring leads in it...is there a reason you can't put a junction box behind the oven instead?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I thought that it would be easier to wire it up in the basement than crawling into the cabinet with the oven along side. I don't know how long the wiring leads are, I will check.

Comment: Also, can you get us make and model info for said double oven?

Comment: Usually the leads are just long enough to allow for the unit to be pulled out and gain access to the Jbox to wire it up. But I don’t know of anything in code that would prevent this as long as the box is accessible in the basement.

Comment: The oven is Bosch 500 series. Did find where it indicates that the cord is 50” https://media3.bosch-home.com/Documents/MCDOC01765194_HBL5651UC.pdf